# Which method actually performs rollover in log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I wanted to know which method actually performs the rollover of files in log4j2. I tried searching for it in the source code, but couldn't find it.

There is a method `public RolloverDescription rollover(final RollingFileManager manager)` in `DefaultRolloverStrategy` class which I overrode in my `CustomStrategy` class only to find that this method doesn't performs the actual rollover.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is actually the [RolloverDescription](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/RolloverDescription.html) which contains two types of actions:

> AsyncAction - Action to be completed after close of current active log file and before next rollover attempt, may be executed asynchronously.
>
> SyncAction - Action to be completed after close of current active log file before returning control to caller.

The part where those actions are being executed is the [RollingFileManager.rollover](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/0c1ad7ccdeb1e03f0bf6a28006030ce57f769685/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/RollingFileManager.java#L344)

```
        final RolloverDescription descriptor = strategy.rollover(this);
        if (descriptor != null) {
            writeFooter();
            closeOutputStream();
            if (descriptor.getSynchronous() != null) {
                LOGGER.debug("RollingFileManager executing synchronous {}", descriptor.getSynchronous());
                try {
                    success = descriptor.getSynchronous().execute();
                } catch (final Exception ex) {
                    success = false;
                    logError("Caught error in synchronous task", ex);
                }
            }

            if (success && descriptor.getAsynchronous() != null) {
                LOGGER.debug("RollingFileManager executing async {}", descriptor.getAsynchronous());
                asyncExecutor.execute(new AsyncAction(descriptor.getAsynchronous(), this));
                releaseRequired = false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

So your CustomStrategy.rollover is what happens in the first line of the code snippet above. The CustomStrategy.rollover returns the RolloverDescription, which consists the action to be executed, as I explained above.